# Locking the field in Excel depending on input from another field

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am taking drop-down input in excel field. Depending on this drop-down input, other field need to be locked and change in color.
I have tried writing below VBA but it is not working. Please let me know simple solution.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If (Sheet1.Range("D2").Value = "New") Then

    Sheet1.Range("G2").Locked = True
    Sheet1.Range("G2").Interior.ColorIndex = 15

Else

    Sheet1.Range("G2").Locked = False
    Sheet1.Range("G2").Interior.ColorIndex = 36

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `Locked` to True or False will have no effect unless the Worksheet is protected. To achieve this your code would also have to temporarily `UnProtect` and then `Protect` the Worksheet.

```
Sheet1.Unprotect
'Lock or unlock cells..
Sheet1.Protect
```

Note that attempting to do this in the `SelectionChange` event is not ideal, as this code runs constantly and disables Undo. It is better to use either a Button or, if the drop-down is an ActiveX ComboBox, use its `Change` event.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it with just Conditional Formatting for the colors, but as others have said, Locking a cell means nothing until you Protect the sheet.